# How do I upgrade ruby to 1.9 that comes with OSX

Tags: ruby

I think my ruby 1.8.7 comes with OSX out-of-the-box. How do I upgrade that to version 1.9. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach is to install rvm so that you do not pollute your default OS X install of Ruby.  See my [blog post on this topic](http://blog.bsodmike.com/2011/04/19/rvm-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/).  Once you have rvm setup, you can set about installing ruby 1.9:

```
rvm install 1.9
rvm use 1.9
```

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly suggest using RVM. This allows you to have multiple versions of ruby as well as gemset within those. Refer to the installation document here.

http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Assuming you have git installed, you can run this command:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

This will install it. Please be sure to read the rest of the instructions. Once it is installed, you can simply run

```
rvm install ruby-1.9
```

Definitely read through the documentation on the site though to fully grasp how to leverage and use rvm.

Best of luck.

Comment: Do I have to delete my old ruby? and How? Thanks

Comment: RVM puts things in it's own area so you do not have to touch the old ruby.

Comment: No, you do not need to.  See my comment below.  You can easily switch back to 1.8.7 by performing `rvm install 1.8.7` and `rvm use 1.8.7`  You have to do this once as rvm stores ruby and all its gems in a different location than your system default install of ruby.